# Existe falha de segurança da aplicação ao usar AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, pdo

Sou programador `HTML/CSS/PHP` a alguns anos e por incrível e mais impossível que parece, só estou entrando no mundo de Javascript com `jQuery` e `AJAX` agora. A minha pergunta é se o nível de segurança é afetado ao passarmos parâmetros por `AJAX` visto que o código fonte do `javascript` fica exposto caso não decidamos criptografá-lo de alguma forma.

Quando por exemplo temos que passar parâmetros para o PHP através do `AJAX`, a não ser que troquemos as variáveis lá dentro do `PHP`, elas ficam meio que descobertas já na passagem de paramentros no `AJAX` além de que as urls, pelo menos eu por falta de conhecimento, iniciante, tenho passado as `urls` absolutas dos arquivos.

Até que ponto isso é perigoso? Até que ponto isso afetaria a segurança do sistema? Lembrando que essa pergunta não está fundamentada em querer opiniões mas sim fundamentos técnicos que expliquem a mesma.

Comment: A resposta do Sergio está correta, mas só pra cobrir todas as bases, favor esclarecer o seguinte: 1) a autenticação do usuário continua usando cookies, ou mudou alguma coisa depois que você passou pra Ajax? 2) Você estava se protegendo contra CSRF antes? Continua fazendo o mesmo agora? 3) Você faz requisições Ajax pra um domínio diferente? (CORS) 4) Outros sites podem fazer requisições Ajax pro seu domínio? (também CORS)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A regra geral é: nunca confie em nada que venha do lado do cliente.

Todo o input que seja feito por javascript tem de ser verificado no lado do servidor. Só quando está a correr PHP pode fazer as verificações que precisa para evitar injeções de código.

Faça o que puder do lado do javascript, e o que fôr util para o usuário, mas depois guarde bem a casa e trate dos dados devidamente, principalmente se houver uma base de dados que vá receber esses dados.

Comment: Então por mais magnifico que seja o Javascript com suas requisições em tempo de execução, devemos ter sempre um pé atrás e tratar tudo que puder dentro do `PHP`?

Comment: @MarcosViniciusNasc.Pereira: exato.

Comment: É recomendável criptografar o código fonte dos scripts client-side ou totalmente desnecessário @Sergio?

Comment: @MarcosViniciusNasc.Pereira: desnecessário. Quem quer vê na mesma, ou faz um código próprio e envia para o servidor na mesma. Dê uma olhada aqui e à explicação a desvendar o código todo: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18834309/2256325

Answer (score 3):

> A minha pergunta é se o nível de segurança é afetado ao passarmos parâmetros por AJAX visto que o código fonte do javascript fica exposto [...]
>   As variáveis lá dentro do PHP, elas ficam meio que descobertas já na passagem de paramentros

Não é um problema que mereça atenção.
Vou apenas acrescentar alguns pontos comparando uma Request Ajax usando método GET e POST.

---

1) Um formulário comum, independente de AJAX, sempre tem os elementos acessíveis, você pode ver os nomes dos campos inclusive altera-los.

```
$.ajax({
        url  : 'page.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : { nome : 'Papa Charlie' }
        ...
    });
```

2) Usando AJAX como GET, simula uma requisição com parâmetro exposto na URL:
`www.dominio.com/page.php?name=Papa Charlie`

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'page.php',
        type: 'GET' ,
        data: 'nome = Papa Charlie',
        ...
});
```

---

Ou seja, no método POST você tem um formulário onde os campos podem ser lidos e editados, e no método GET você tem a simulação de uma URL, e ambos a identificação dos parâmetros é visível. *Independentemente do uso do AJAX na sua aplicação, os parâmetros sempre estão disponíveis*

Não precisa alterar os nomes no PHP, basta verificar para garantir que os valores recebidos **SEJAM** do tipo esperado.

Answer (score 1):

Concordando com a resposta do 'sergio'.... A minha resposta vem no sentido de introduzir a "sessão" na resposta.

Não é recomendável nem de realizar do ponto de vista de segurança passar informação sensível do php para o ajax e vice versa... Reforço informação sensível.

Mesmo com comunicaçoes por "https" que introduz um maior nível de segurança, nada está seguro.

Para o efeito e em resposta ao colocado na pergunta, toda a informação sensível nunca poderá ou deverá sair da alçada do servidor ou do cluster de servidores conforme a situação. Sempre que possível utiliza a sessão para guardar um ou outro campo, ou utiliza a base de dados entre chamadas pois é na realidade o único local onde a informação se irá manter persistente.

O sistema deve ainda de contemplar verificações sobre quem realiza qualquer chamada Ajax... Negando quem realize uma chamada fora do âmbito da aplicação e para isso existem várias soluções como por exemplo um Token por cada chamada.

Ps: o método POST sempre. quando a segurança é uma preocupação.

Comment: Parece fazer sentido a resposta, só esta linha que não ficou clara pra mim: "Ps: o método POST sempre. quando a segurança é uma preocupação.". Tirando o fato de não aparecer no URL, qual seria a vantagem do post em relação à segurança?

Comment: O facto do não aparecer no URL...  Logo mais difícil de ser legível e manipulavel... Coloca ao  POST a escolha lógica. Por isso escolher sempre. No entanto e por si nada resolve... A não ser com a implementaçao que referi.

Comment: Imaginei. Era mais para ter uma idéia se havia algum motivo a mais para a recomendação. Grato pela atenção!